# Get a CommunicationObjectFaultedException

Tags: wcf, exception, silverlight-4.0, iis-7, net.tcp

I have a WCF NET.TCP Service hosted in my local IIS 7 web server.  A silverlight application accesses  this service.  The silverlight app is embedded in an aspx page of another website hosted on the same local web server. Everything works fine when I access this website on my local computer, but when I use another computer to access the website the silverlight app  raises an exception as follows:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException [CommunicationObjectFaulted1]
Arguments: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60831.0&File=System.ServiceModel.dll&Key=CommunicationObjectFaulted1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running?

I ask as Windows Azure causes this if the `web.config` is read only.

**edit**

As a means of trying to catch it, something to be wary of is the `using` block to initialise the WCF service. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2007/04/25/why-using-is-bad-for-your-wcf-service-host.aspx).

This states that there is an initial exception> (typically to do with the config) and that the finally section of the using block, as it attempts to close the service is when this exception is thrown.

Comment: My local IIS is running on windows 7

Comment: I have checked the property of the web.config, the "read-only" is not chosen